# Question about notation in Introduction to Statistical Learning

Tags: notation

I've been working my way through the problems in the book "Introduction to Statistical Learning". I have a question about the notation in Question 5 from Chapter 3 (screenshot below). What does $x_{i'}$ mean exactly, in comparison to $x_{i}$.

[image]

Comment: $i'$ is just a dummy variable (note that it only appears in summations). You could replace it by $j$ and the meaning wouldn't change.

Comment: Do you mean it's basically a different index than $i$?

Comment: Yes, think of $i$ as being a fixed but arbitrary index. Think of $i'$ as a variable that only appears as a way of expressing summations. It might be less confusing if you replace the $i$s in the middle equation by some other variable (because in the middle equation, $i$ is a dummy variable).

Comment: Would you be able to expand it in an answer form? I don't quite get why $i$ is fixed. When you say "fix", I interpret it (probably wrongly!) to mean it does not vary and is fixed to one value. But if it doesn't vary, what's the point of summation in the numerator?

Comment: When I tried to compute the slope coefficient (with the intercept removed) in `R`, I do this `sum(x*y)/sum(x^2)` where `x` is the predictor variable and `y` is the response variable. This makes me wonder what the purpose of the different indices is since both the numerator and denominator require summing all $n$ elements

Comment: This use of two different indices and especially of the $\prime$ in the bottom is rather unfortunate.

Comment: clarifying question, but are the dimensions of x (1xp)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is useless to use a new index $i'$ in the expression $\hat\beta$ is useless: you can write 
$$\hat\beta=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i}{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2}.$$
But now, it is ambiguous to strictly replace $\hat\beta$ with this expression in $\hat y_i=x_i\hat\beta$:
$$
\hat y_i=x_i\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i}{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2}.
$$
because $i$ appears as fixed as well as a summation index in the same expression.
Then we need to use a new index:
$$
\hat y_i=x_i\frac{\sum_{j=1}^nx_jy_j}{\sum_{j=1}^nx_j^2}.
$$
Now the question is to write $\hat y_i$ as a linear combination of the $y_j$'s. From the above equality : 
$$
\hat y_i=\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\frac{x_ix_j}{\sum_{j=1}^nx_j^2}\right)y_j
$$
but this is ambiguous again. We need a new index again:
$$
\hat y_i=\sum_{i'=1}^n\left(\frac{x_ix_{i'}}{\sum_{j=1}^nx_j^2}\right)y_{i'} = \sum_{i'=1}^na_{i'}y_{i'}
$$
with $a_{i'}=\dfrac{x_ix_{i'}}{\sum_{j=1}^nx_j^2}$.